# What does $|$ mean?

Tags: notation

I came across this notation in a [solution manual](https://linearalgebras.com/understanding-analysis-exercise-1-2.html). It appears in the solution to Exercise 1.2.2. as $3|2^p$. Any idea what it could mean?

Comment: Generally it means $3$ divides $2^p$

Comment: I think you should put that as the answer

Comment: It can also be seen as "such that" in some places too though. But in the context they said, it definitely means "divides" as said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally $a \mid b$ means $a$ divides $b$ where $a,b\ne 0$ are integers. Since $\frac{b}{a}$ is a rational number it is sometime cumbersome to say that $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer even though it means the same thing. Even we can write in words that " $b$ is divisible by $a$" but $a \mid b$ convention is lot more easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It means "divides", i.e. "3 divides $2^p$.  Formally:

> There exists an integer $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $3\cdot k =  2^p$.

However, depending over which set or ring you are acting, divisibility is defined the same (in a broader context) but might spell out differently in the details, for example when you are over a ring of polynomials like $\Bbb Z[x]$ or over the ring of integers of some algebraic number field like $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$.

By the way, the symbol for "does not divide" is $\nmid$.

Comment: You meant to say $k \cdot 3 = 2^p$.

Comment: Ooops, yes of course.  It's fixed.